# How to check if user already exists using C# and Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class formregister : Form
    {
        public formregister()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db_users.mdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // how to check if the user is already exists?
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textusername.Text == "" && textpassword.Text == "" && textconpassword.Text == "" && textboxemailaddress.Text == "" && textboxgender.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Fields", "Registration Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (textpassword.Text == textconpassword.Text)
            {
                con.Open();

                string register = "INSERT INTO tbl_users VALUES ('" + textusername.Text + "','" + textpassword.Text + "','" +textboxemailaddress.Text+ "','" + textboxgender.Text + "')";

                cmd = new OleDbCommand(register , con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

                textusername.Text = "";
                textpassword.Text = "";
                textconpassword.Text = "";
                textboxemailaddress.Text = "";
                textboxgender.Text = "";

                MessageBox.Show("Your account has been successfully created", "Registration Success" , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password does not match, please re-enter", "Registration Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textpassword.Text = "";
                textconpassword.Text = "";
                textconpassword.Focus();
```

Comment: What actual problem are you having?

Comment: @nick SQL injection is the biggest actual problem they're having, I'd say! :)

Comment: @david just insert your user and catch the exception that occurs if you try and register a username that already exists (you made username the primary key, right?). Also, take a read of http://Bobby-tables.com first the home page, then the About section

Comment: And: never store passwords in a database. Use a salted hash instead.

Comment: How to check if email already exist on my database. tablename = tbl_users, column is = Email. what is the correct command.